# How can I convert a string into a variable name in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have four pre-defined input keywords. (e.g num1, num2, etc) Based on these keywords the user will define a formula in a textbox.
Example:
num1 + num2 * num3 * (num3-num1)

Since this input will be taken from a textbox it will be a string.
How can convert these keywords from string to the variable name and execute the formula in my code?

I didn't find any suitable answer for this in other threads.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Try a Dictionary.

Comment: @adv12 Most likely, I remember thinking like this when I was newer to programming and its probably almost always the wrong way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the `DynamicExpresso` nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicExpresso.Core/

Then you can do something like:

```
var s = "num1 + num2 * num3 * (num3-num1)";
var interpreter = new Interpreter();

int num1 = 11;
int num2 = 12;
int num3 = 13;

var parameters = new[]
{
    new Parameter("num1", num1),
    new Parameter("num2", num2),
    new Parameter("num3", num3)
};
var result = interpreter.Eval(s, parameters);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 323
```

Comment: can we use this package to perform Max and Min operation? Example:
Max(@num1,@num2) should be evaluated as Math.Max(num1, num2)

Comment: Yeah, try it out on the online playground site - http://dynamic-expresso.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score -2):

You could do that by building a corresponding expression tree:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/